Guardar archivo en una carpeta de la pc del cliente Asp.net core MVC
Queria saber si alguien sabe como guardar un archivo en una carpeta de la PC del cliente.
Aqui es donde subiria mi archivo en html
<div class="col-md-6" id="COMPROBANTE" name="COMPROBANTE">
    <b><label for="inputName5" class="form-label">Subir archivo</label></b>
    <input type="file" name="COMPROBANTES" id="COMPROBANTES"/>
</div>

Entonces digamos que al querer dar clic en un boton me guarde la imagen en una carpeta de la pc.
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda, saludos.
